# I need a query to solve the case I mentioned below

Tags: sql, database

STUDENT table which is used to store the student info and COURSE table which is used to store the Course info. the relationship between STUDENT and COURSE is one to many.

"Not Equal" and "Not Contains" are not giving the correct results incase of one to many relationship.(if we make the direct left join with COURSE table)

- [sample query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkQzn.png)
- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d38d/1)

**Table: STUDENT**

```
id          name
----------- ----------
1           a         
2           b         
3           c
```

**Table: COURSE**

```
id          name       student
----------- ---------- ----------
10          x          1         
11          y          1         
11          y          2         
10          x          3
```

In the example, I would like to obtain all students who are not associated with the course 'y'.  But, when I add join and then apply filter, if a student (here student 'a') is associated with 'y' and another subject, he is shown in result.  But, I
should not have student 'a' in the result as he is associated with 'y'.

In the following query, I was only expecting a single result

```sql
SELECT * FROM stu 
JOIN cour ON stu.id = cour.student
WHERE cour.name != 'y'
```

```
id          name       id          name       student
----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           a          10          x          1         
3           c          10          x          3
```

And multiple logical operations are also possible in the criteria. could you please suggest a query to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give a query which does not work?

Comment: Mysql and postgresql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: Your query is incorrect, usually for this it is easier to use a `NOT EXISTS` instead of joins to identify the results to return, I can post more detail in an answer if this gets re-opened: `SELECT * FROM stu 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM cour WHERE stu.id = cour.student AND cour.name = 'y')`

Comment: Also strictly speaking you should have 3 tables, stu, cour and stu_to_cor.  Split your course into just the course id & name then stu_to_cour has course_id and student_id

Chris Schaller's answer still generally stands as the right one in that scenario.